# CSP Violation : Inline Style in innerHTML of a library

Tags: content-security-policy

I have set up the Content Security Policy in my header. Everything is working fine.

Problem: One of the libraries I use, use innerHtml with inline CSS. This generates a CSP error:

```
svgbundle.ts:53 Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self' 'sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='. Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-0EZqoz+oBhx7gF4nvY2bSqoGyy4zLjNF+SDQXGp/ZrY='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.
```

The code that generates the error (which I can't modify, it's a lib) :

[image]

I added the hash in my style-src, but I guess it doesn't work according to the last sentence of the error
unsafe-hashes is really the last possible solution?

Answer (score -1):

Try to add this rule :

```
style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';
```

All my CSP rules with which innerHTML is accepted  :

```
<meta
  http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy"
  content="default-src 'self'; 
            img-src 'self' data: https://* ; 
            child-src 'none';
            frame-src 'self' https://*;
            style-src 'unsafe-inline' 'self';
            script-src 'nonce-azerty123' 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline';
            script-src-elem 'nonce-azerty123' 'unsafe-eval'  'unsafe-inline';
            worker-src 'self';
            base-uri 'self'"
/>
```

Comment: 'unsafe-inline' is simply turning off the security. It is not the solution and any client who runs even a basic security check of your software will not accept it.